# What do you call those "round checkboxes"?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

The thing a blue arrow points at is called a "checkbox", right? What do you call the round elements, the ones that look like bullet points?

[image]

Comment: A software developer might call those things *radio buttons* but I do not think that term is used by the general populace.  To my knowledge there is no generally understood term for radio button.

Comment: I call them that, and I'm a software user.

Comment: Our office uses software which includes radio buttons, and that is what the training documents call them. If an ordinary person can know what a check box is, why not a radio button?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Radio Button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button): "A **radio button** or **option button** is a graphical control element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of mutually exclusive options."

Comment: Why would you need to call them anything other than "check buttons" or "radio buttons"?

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther "This term describing a programming concept is understood only by programmers" doesn't strike me as a very relevant issue.

Comment: @Acccumulation - Nice example of a hyperbolic response..  Who are you quoting?   Are you quoting your internal misconceptions?  I did not say it was **only understood by programmers**.  See posts concerning *orthogonally adjacent* for an example of why I thought it might be relevant.  Apparently that term is not understood by the general public.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther "I do not think that term is used by the general populace" is the same as "only understood by programmers".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey because you're old enough to remember radios!

Comment: @RonJohn - I have a Sony AM/FM radio in the kitchen which is about 5 years old.

Comment: @RonJohn - it's really cool. It runs on AC or 4 AA batteries (I have rechargeables), you can carry it around, it doesn't need internet or AC power to work. I am a big fan of BBC Radio 4.

Comment: My first exposure to these terms was in the Apple document named "Inside Macintosh".  My copy was a pre-release version in 1984.  If I remember correctly, the authors made a big thing about the analogy to the (usually rectangular) buttons on a car radio.  When I left that job 7 years later, I asked if I could take that copy home.  "No, no, the company paid for it".  When I went back a month later to meet someone for lunch, my office had been cleared out an every thing on that shelf had been thrown out - grrrr.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The round item you have indicated is a **radio button**

> radio button
>
> noun
>
> (computing)
>
> ​(on a computer screen) a small circle that you click on in order to
> make a particular choice. The radio button is then marked with a dot
> (= a small round mark) to show that it has been selected.

[Radio button (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/radio-button#:%7E:text=%2F%CB%88re%C9%AAdi%C9%99%CA%8A%20b%CA%8Ctn%2F-,%2F%CB%88re%C9%AAdi%C9%99%CA%8A%20b%CA%8Ctn%2F,Questions%20about%20grammar%20and%20vocabulary%3F)

The difference between checkboxes and radio buttons is that you can check more than one checkbox in a group of checkboxes, but select only one radio button in a group of radio buttons.

The name comes from old-fashioned radios and TVs with buttons (round or not) which could be tuned to different radio stations or TV channels. If one button was already pressed in, and you pressed a different one, the first button popped out, and the second one stayed pressed in.

[image]

[image]

Note: Although British English speakers are familiar with, and use, 'check', many call this symbol  `✓` a 'tick', so we may say we 'tick' or 'untick' 'tick boxes'. Interestingly, this UK illustration for an article about 'tickboxes' shows a sheet headed 'checklist':

[image]

Comment: I live in Australia and have never heard the word 'radio button'. I do not doubt that it's the correct term, but I don't know how much luck you'll have using it in conversation

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140189/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-harvey-what-do-you-call-those-round-checkboxes).

Comment: "Interestingly, this UK illustration for an article about 'tickboxes' shows a sheet headed 'checklist'" - because it's a list of items to "check", not simply to "tick". Different meaning to the "check" in "checkbox". It might as well have been called a "To-do list" or "Task list".

Comment: @MrWhite - or, as they call them in my legal services office, where they form a part of some workflows, 'tick lists'.

Comment: waited for 30 years for this explanantion

Answer (score 12):

**Software:**

If you can check more than one, it's a checkbox. If you can only check one, it's a radio button.

I just wanted to note that if we're talking about software terms, the name denotes the functionality, not the appearance. Radio buttons are where you can only select one of a choice of entries. Selecting a different entry unselects your previous choice. If you made them look like squares, and made selecting it put a check in the square, it would still be a radio button because that's the functionality being used.

Similarly, if you made a selection of circles and filling in the circle selected the item and you could select multiple circles, then the functionality still defines it as a checkbox even though you've made it look like radio buttons.

**Outside of software:**

e.g., in a [Scantron form](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scantron), the term used is usually "***bubbles***". Fill in the bubble.

Comment: Good secondary info.

Comment: Check the interface guides for Windows and Mac and you will get the names for everything that has ever appeared in a computer UI. BTW, Windows previously called these "option buttons" to be different from the Mac OS "radio buttons"

Comment: I think bubble will be way less known than radio button.

Comment: "If you can only check one, it's a radio button." Agreed, it comes from the design of radios and similar devices with a row of buttons, typically for use in selecting the programme source. For example LW, MW, SW, Phono, Aux. Since you can only listen to one at a time, press one button down and all the others pop up.